# How to restrict number of items in cart to 3 in codeiginter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework  for building E-commerce website.
Is it possible to restrict the number of items in cart to 3 .
Quantity can be any number. But number of items should be 3.
Is there anyway to restrict number of items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can used simple `if else` condition using `count`. Example

```
$total_items= count($this->cart->contents());
if($total_items >= 3){
$message="cart has 3 items OR cart is full";
return false;//or redirect 
}else{
//add items into cart
}
```

Comment: Works Fine Thank You.